# How accurate can decimals of CSS pixels go

Tags: html, css

I've been specifying widths in percentages for an approach for a site I've got and used the Firefox Inspector to see what widths are being calculated. The Inspector often gives three or more numbers after the decimal point for the pixels.
I'm not worried about weather pixels get rounded up or down or not but was wondering what is the smallest value that could be returned.

Comment: Really...once you get down to 1/1000 of a pixel...what does it matter? Struggling to find a use case for knowing this. In any case, it's likely to be browser dependent,

Comment: I'm using media queries and I get a bit of an inconstancy when changing from one to another and I know it because I'm half way between to two and the only way that can happen if with a fraction of a pixel.
I want to add some decimals so that I can be between so I need to know how accurate to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an interesting reading http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

Comment: I had a read but I only deals with the number of decimal places for percentages. I really need to know the most accurate value I might get from a pixel.

Comment: The `Round pixels` in the `Browser Table` shows how the browsers round pixels when you use decimals. I'm not sure how accurate can decimals go (I cannot find it) but the browsers will always round the decimals.

Comment: I know that will round it if I specify it. Firefox Inspector give me ususually three decimal places. I haven't seen any more accurate than that but I'll update this if I do.

Comment: I see what you mean about rounding them off. I had a width that was a bit over a width I'd specified for an action. Later on the width was still a bit over but the decimal value was less but it had obviously rounded it down this time.